# How to rotate big structures 90 degrees in Minecraft Pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a big sculpture in Minecraft on my computer and wanted to clone it so I did it cloned but it's the wrong way. Could someone tell me a command to rotate it 90 degrees?

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is 32*32*32 or lesser, use a structure block to save the structure, then load up its rotated form

Read about using it [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block)

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tC8KmJAiDg)
To See a Video Tutorial on using it(Made during the snapshots before its release)

Comment: Just saying, i don't know how to rotate larger structures
Also, what is the problem in sharing videos and links? why do i get down voted whenever I share that?

Comment: We strive to ensure that answers can stand on their own. What you currently have we generally refer to as a, "link-only answer". That means your answer doesn't answer the question without the links. This is bad for us, as links rot, and require readers to click another link to get the information. Please try to summarize the relevant information from your links.

Comment: @Frank ok i will do so when i have time